# Conditions of $f=a+bx+cz+dx^2+exz+fz^2+...$ such that its tangent line is $z=0$ and inflection point is at the origin.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, projective-geometry

Let $x,z$ be coordinates on $k^2$ and $f\in k[x,z]$; write $f$ as

$$f=a+bx+cz+dx^2+exz+fz^2+...$$

Write down the conditions in terms of $a,b,c,...$ such that

(a) $P=(0,0)\in C: (f=0)$;

(b) the tangent line to $C$ at $P$ is $z=0$;

(c) $P$ is an inflection point of $C$ with $z=0$ as the tangent line.

My solution:

(a) This is very trivial, we can see $a=0$ gives $P\in C$;

(b) Parametrize the line $L$ passing through $(0,0)$ as

$$x=x_0t, y=y_0t$$

So $f|L=a+bx_0t+cz_0t+dx_0^2t^2+ex_0z_0t^2+fz_0^2t^2+...=g(t)$. For it to have tangent line at $(0,0)$, we need $g'(0)=0$. This gives $bx_0+cz_0=0$. If the tangent line is $z=0$, we must have $b=0, c\ne 0$.

(c) Set the same parametric equation as (b). For $(0,0)$ to be an inflection point, we need $g''(0)=0$, which gives

$$dx_0^2+ex_0z_0+fz_0^2=0$$

In part (b), there is a tangent line $z=0$, that can lead to $b=0$. But for this inflection point, no more condition is given. So I am not sure how to go on. What does this imply about the conditions of $d,e,f$?

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:** 
$f|L$ should have a zero of multiplicity $\ge 3$. So $a,b,d=0$ and $c\ne 0$.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with elliptic curves and the tag (elliptic-curves) is misleading : there are no elliptic curves in $k^2$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Sorry, I put elliptic curves because the next question of the set asks to show that any cubic in $P_k^2$ with an inflexion point can be transformed into $Y^2Z=X^3+aX^2Z+bXZ^2+cZ^3$. And the other questions are about group law on elliptic curves. So I thought they are related.

Comment: Your edit is correct but you should add $c\neq0$ to the conditions $a=b=d=0$: else your curve will be singular and there will be no tangent line .

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Thanks, I'll add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Look at the [Resultant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) and [Discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of the two polynomials when they intersect, to see if the intersection is transverse, tangential, etc., and also to determine point of inflection, etc..

To ease this stuff, consult the paper:

The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves. by Tate, John T. in Inventiones mathematicae volume 23; pp. 179 - 206

where the author has worked out some of these things in the first few pages already. Googling will give you one copy or other of this paper.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! I will look into them and get back to you.

Comment: @KittyL Please check first couple of chapters of the book, J. W. S. Cassels,  Lectures on Elliptic Curves, if available.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with elliptic curves and your references are as vague as they are irrelevant.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg The OP mentioned elliptic curves in his question. I see that you objected to that too.

Comment: Thanks. The references are too advanced for me to understand.  I realized what I missed though.